# cakephp virtual fields with subquery and if

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have a `Category` table with a `name` field.
I want to be able to overwrite that name using a `PartnerCategory` Table and join it.

So usually I would get the `Category` like this:

```
$options = array(
    'contain' => array('PartnerCategory'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Category.slug' => $slug,
        'Category.status' => true,
    )
);
$category = $this->Category->find('first', $options);
```

And then check, if `ParentCategory.name` is not empty and replace the `Category.name` with it.

Overwriting the name with php is tedious so I checked virtual fields.

I can overwrite the `Category.name` using this:

```
$this->virtualFields = array(
    'name' => 'SELECT name FROM app_partner_categories WHERE category_id = 1 AND partner_id = 60'
);
```

But if the `name` in the `PartnerCategory` table is empty or no mathes are found, the `Category.name` would be null.

How can I overwrite `Category.name` only if `PartnerCategory.name` is found?

Comment: Can you post what exactly have you tried ?

Comment: @Indrajit I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this could be a possible solution:

```
$joins = array(array('table' => 'app_partner_categories',
                     'alias' => 'PartnerCategory',
                     'type' => 'INNER',
                     'conditions' => array(
                                     'PartnerCategory.category_id = Category.id'
                                        ) 
                                    )
                            );

$options = array(
'fields' => array('IF(PartnerCategory.name IS NULL or PartnerCategory.name = "", Category.name, PartnerCategory.name) as overwritten_name'),
'joins' => $joins,
'conditions' => array(
    'Category.slug' => $slug,
    'Category.status' => true,
 )
);
$category = $this->Category->find('first', $options);
```